# Continuous function from non-compact space onto compact space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

> Give an example of metric spaces $M_1$ and $M_2$ and a continuous function $f$ from $M_1$ onto $M_2$ such that $M_2$ is compact, but $M_1$ is not compact.

So there must exist a sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ with no convergent subsequence in $M_1$, but any sequence in $M_2$ must have a convergent subsequence. In particular, $f(x_1),f(x_2),\ldots$ must have a subsequence that converges to $f(a)$ for some $a\in M_1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: A one-point space is compact and metrizable. Constant functions are continuous.

Comment: Okay, never thought of constant functions. Then just take $M_1$ to be any non-compact set, say the open interval $(0,1)$, and that's it.

Comment: @PJMiller: Yep: it really is that easy.

Comment: Right, the hard part is to know what example to come up with. Thanks!

Comment: @PJMiller: You’re welcome! One useful heuristic when hunting for examples is to try first to meet some of the requirements in the simplest possible way; here, for instance, you might ask yourself what the simplest sort of compact space is. The idea is to try to simplify the setting in hopes that it will then be easier to see what else has to be done. (Like all heuristics, it often fails.)

Answer (score 7):

What about $\sin\colon \mathbb R\to [-1,1]$?

Comment: Another easy example here. I just couldn't think of these!

Comment: Don't get carried away with abstractions all the time, and try to draw pictures!